# iOS: why can't I add two NSTimeIntervals together?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, nstimeinterval

[According to this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215234/how-to-add-the-output-of-multiple-timers)
I should be able to simply += two NSTimeIntervals together... but I can't.
I'm trying to handle hitting 'pause' on a stop watch and being able to continue by using a 'running counter' so to speak of an NSTimeInterval called totalDuration.
But when I do the following

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
// Add the saved interval
totalDuration += timeInterval;
```

I get:

`.../Views/bdNewTrackViewController.m:506:19: Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *') and 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double'))`

baffled...

Comment: What is the totalduration data type here??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `totalDuration` variable isn't declared as an `NSTimeInterval`; it's declared as a pointer to an `NSTimeInterval` (`NSTimeInterval *`). Drop the asterisk in the declaration for `totalDuration` and you should be good.